# Are there any generic (not dependent on symptoms) ways to find parasite infections?

Tags: human-biology, parasitology

Are there any generic ways to determine if a person is infected with a parasite?

With "generic ways" I mean ways that do not rely on symptoms caused by a particular parasite. Also I am mainly concerned by parasites that are too large for the immune system to completely handle on its own (such as worms).

For example, can parasites be seen in x-rays, MRI scans, or through some body fluid samples?

Comment: It all depends on the parasite...

Comment: For some, you can do a stool examination for ova and parasites. The tests really depend on the parasite, as @Matt has said. Eosinophilia is common with roundworms as well, but it's nonspecific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind would be eosinophils numeration. It is a specific type of white blood cell that handles parasitic infections. So in most cases, a blood sample would show an increase in this type of cell.